# How to use a plugin without using ionic-native?

Tags: cordova, azure, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want add the cordova plugin: [cordova-plguin-ms-adal](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova). Because this plugin is not supported in the ionic-native. I don't know how to implement myself, so I open an issue and hope they will merge this plugin very soon.

In the meantime, I can't wait. So is there any way to use this plugin without using ionic-native?

I tried the following code in my **home.ts**, but failed to reach.

```
windows.plugins.Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(s);
```

or directly

```
Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(s);
```

Note: 
- Microsoft and ADAL are the namespaces of the plugin
- AuthenticationContext is the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cordova plugin in ionic2 though the plugin is not supported by ionic-native. Add the required plugin to your project.

Open the file "**Plugins.xml**" and check for the **target** value under **clobbers** tag. In your case, it is Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext where **Microsoft** is the base class.

Open the ts file where you want to use the plugin.Use `declare var Microsoft: any;`under import as it is a base class. Then call the method as `Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext.your_method()`

Comment: I'd like to use this plugin on my ionic2 project.
https://github.com/Ti-webdev/cordova-plugin-push-baidu
but this is not working, Please help for this.
Thanks