# Getting issue while running custom plugin in ionic 2 for android

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have changed my inbuilt device plugin to custom plugin and have tried to invoke it by importing using path.
But how to excess it in my typescript file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as custom from '../../cordova/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/custom.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

constructor()
{
  this.Device();
}

 Device() {
    console.log(custom.cordova);
}

}
```

have tried to access custom.cordova method but got nothing while running

Comment: "No need to import it, just use it directly like `device.model`" Referring to an answer posted here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-how-to-get-device-details/43740

Comment: Oh oops, outdated probably, depends on your ionic version. Latest is `import { Device } from 'ionic-native';` and then `console.log(Device.model);` for example

Comment: no i want to add custom plugin which does not exist in ionic 2 .i have tried all this and its working fine but how to add custom plugin in ionic 2 .As i havent found any neccassary documentation till now so if any body can assist

Comment: may be this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696420/how-to-use-a-plugin-without-using-ionic-native/38702473#38702473 could help you to use custom plugins in ionic2

Comment: can you please let me know what exactly the import he has used and the target value in clobbers file. Actually i have a custom plugin how i import its as import * as custom from '../../../plugins/custom/www/....' and have used  declare var custom:any;      command also but it is giving error ..just let me know  how can i rectify this