# Ionic build cannot find module error. How to import Android plugin?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to develop an Android Plugin to use in an Ionic app.

I created the app with a starter project already provided by Ionic using `ionic start myApp tabs`.

I have also created, in a different folder, my plugin, that contains the following files.

> plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="location-plugin" version="0.0.1">
<name>GSLocationManager</name>
<description>Location Plugin</description>
<license>MIT</license>
<keywords>cordova,device,sensors,location</keywords>

<js-module name="LocationManager" src="www/LocationManager.js">
    <clobbers target="LocationManager" />
</js-module>

<engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.6.0"></engine>
</engines>

<platform name="android">
  <preference name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" default="11+"/>
  <preference name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" default="26+"/>
  <preference name="ICON" default="@mipmap/icon" />
  <preference name="SMALL_ICON" default="@mipmap/icon" />
  <preference name="ACCOUNT_NAME" default="@string/app_name" />
  <preference name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" default="@string/app_name" />
  <preference name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" default="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
  <preference name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" default="$PACKAGE_NAME" />

  <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" />
  <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" />
  <framework src="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" />
  <!-- <framework src="android/dependencies.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/> -->

  <source-file src="path/to/locationmanager/GSLocationManager.java"
               target-dir="path/to/locationmanager"></source-file>

  <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location" />
  </config-file>

  <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="GSLocationManager">
          <param name="android-package" value="android.package.locationmanager.GSLocationManager" />
      </feature>
  </config-file>
</platform>
```

> locationManager.js

```
var GSLocationManager = {
  getCurrentLocation: function(success, failure) {
    exec(success, failure, 'GSLocationManager', 'getCurrentLocation', []);
  }
}

module.exports = GSLocationManager;
```

> GSLocationManager.java

```
package android.package.locationmanager;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class GSLocationManager extends CordovaPlugin {

    private JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    // at the initialize function, we can configure the tools we want to use later, like the sensors
    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);

    }

    // safety unregistering from the events if the application stops somehow
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    // this is the main part of the plugin, we have to handle all of the actions sent from the js
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if ("getCurrentLocation".equals(action)) {
            Location location = getCurrentLocation();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
            json.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
            callbackContext.success(json);
            return true;
        }
        return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private Location getCurrentLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Location lastKnownGPSLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return lastKnownGPSLocation;
    }
}
```

Then I created a package.json for my plugin usign **plugman** 
And after that, added my android plugin to my Ionic project by doing
`ionic cordova plugin add path/to/my/plugin`

**But I cannot seem to be able to import my plugin to `app.module.ts` using `import { GSLocationManager } from 'globespinning-location-plugin'`
I try to build but CLI says `ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(12,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'globespinning-location-plugin'.`**

Any idea where the error is?
How should I import a plugin created by me, and referenced from a local folder?
I want to be able to call `GSLocationManager.getCurrentLocation()` inside my ionic app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Tachyon and @SeunBincom answer was helpful, but the problem was with my `plugin.xml` file. With the help of Android Studio I was able to debug it and finally got it working.

The xml ended up like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        id="globespinning-location-plugin" version="0.0.1">
    <name>LocationManager</name>
    <description>Globespinning Location Plugin</description>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords>cordova,device,sensors,location</keywords>

    <js-module name="LocationManager" src="www/locationManager.js">
        <clobbers target="LocationManager" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="android">
      <preference name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" default="11+"/>
      <preference name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" default="26+"/>
      <preference name="ICON" default="@mipmap/icon" />
      <preference name="SMALL_ICON" default="@mipmap/icon" />
      <preference name="ACCOUNT_NAME" default="@string/app_name" />
      <preference name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" default="@string/app_name" />
      <preference name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" default="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
      <preference name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" default="$PACKAGE_NAME" />

      <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" />
      <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" />
      <framework src="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" />
      <framework src="src/android/dependencies.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>

      <source-file src="src/android/com/globespinning/ionic/locationmanager/GSLocationManager.java"
                   target-dir="src/com/globespinning/ionic/locationmanager"></source-file>

      <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location" />
      </config-file>

      <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
          <feature name="LocationManager">
              <param name="android-package" value="com.globespinning.ionic.locationmanager.GSLocationManager" />
          </feature>
      </config-file>
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to go ahead and run `ionic cordova plugin add "folder path of your custom plugin"` after that in the `.ts` file you want to use it in you want to declare the following, `declare var myPlugin: any;`

Once you have declared the plugin you can go ahead and use it as follows:

```
myPlugin.myFuntion((data) => {
        console.log(data);
},(err) => {
        console.log(err);
});
```

So in your case you'd use the following:

```
declare var GSLocationManager: any;

....

GSLocationManager.getCurrentLocation().then((data) => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to [@tachyon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54861246/9891929) answer, here are some stuff to note.

- You need to create a declaration (.d.ts) file for your plugin js before you can use the `import * from * syntax`. it is not required in this case tho.
- check if you have accurately defined the namespace for the js methods. yours is here `<clobbers target="LocationManager" />`

Therefore, here is how to implement such in your case;

**In the .TS File you wish to execute the function**

```
// at the top of the file. after all the import statements
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  // i'm using this as an example.
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';  // you need the platform

declare var LocationManager;
...
constructor(
private platform: Platform
){
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   // we will make use of the plugin here
   console.log('LocationManager: ', LocationManager); // we can check if it exist by logging it out to the console
   if (LocationManager) {
      LocationManager.GSLocationManager.getCurrentLocation(
         success => {
            console.log('LocationManager: Got Location: ', success);
         }, error => {
            console.log('LocationManager: Err Getting Location: ', error);
         }
      );
    }
  });
}
```

you can read more here:
[How to use a plugin without using ionic-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696420/how-to-use-a-plugin-without-using-ionic-native),
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html

Answer (score -1):

If the import fails this could be very likely related to your tsconfig.json or your angular module (app.module.ts). Check if the file in included and not.

You only posted your Java-Files. Are you sure this runs on a browser?

Comment: I've only posted 1 java file. I posted my plugin's files. I'm not sure if the js file is correct.